# Cannot connect to an enterprise WiFi network after an upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, network-manager, macbook-pro, 19.10, wpa-supplicant

The network uses PEAP authentication with MSCHAPv2. During a connection attempt, the following is added to `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov wpa_supplicant[887]: EAP-MSCHAPV2: Authentication succeeded
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov wpa_supplicant[887]: EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov wpa_supplicant[887]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov wpa_supplicant[887]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 84:18:3a:08:80:8c completed [id=0 id_str=]
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.898898] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.898952] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 887 at drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/cfg80211.c:5208 brcmf_cfg80211_set_pmk.cold+0xc/0x18 [brcmfmac]
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.898953] Modules linked in: xt_nat xt_tcpudp veth tg3 xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc rfcomm pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) aufs vboxdrv(OE) overlay bnep nls_iso8859_1 btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth joydev bcm5974 ecdh_generic input_leds ecc snd_hda_codec_cirrus snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_core snd_seq_midi_event snd_hwdep mei_hdcp snd_rawmidi snd_pcm intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm applesmc irqbypass input_polldev intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_seq brcmfmac brcmutil snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211 snd intel_pch_thermal bdc_pci mei_me soundcore mei sbs sbshc acpi_als kfifo_buf apple_gmux industrialio apple_bl mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.898988]  ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt amdgpu amd_iommu_v2 gpu_sched hid_apple hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel radeon i2c_algo_bit ttm aesni_intel drm_kms_helper aes_x86_64 crypto_simd syscopyarea cryptd sysfillrect glue_helper sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm i2c_i801 lpc_ich thunderbolt libahci video
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899008] CPU: 1 PID: 887 Comm: wpa_supplicant Tainted: G        W  OE     5.3.0-19-generic #20-Ubuntu
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899009] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro11,5/Mac-06F11F11946D27C5, BIOS MBP114.88Z.0172.B07.1510261437 10/26/2015
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899024] RIP: 0010:brcmf_cfg80211_set_pmk.cold+0xc/0x18 [brcmfmac]
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899027] Code: ff e9 4f 38 fd ff 48 c7 c7 f8 ad 80 c0 e8 c8 90 b0 d5 0f 0b b8 ea ff ff ff e9 b2 38 fd ff 48 c7 c7 f8 ad 80 c0 e8 b0 90 b0 d5 <0f> 0b b8 ea ff ff ff e9 fb 38 fd ff 48 8b 7b 10 41 89 c0 44 89 e1
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899028] RSP: 0018:ffffbfb503413a38 EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899030] RAX: 0000000000000024 RBX: ffffa0e3e1e09000 RCX: 0000000000000000
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899031] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffa0e3ef057448 RDI: ffffa0e3ef057448
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899032] RBP: ffffbfb503413a48 R08: ffffa0e3ef057448 R09: 0000000000000004
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899033] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffbfb503413a58
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899034] R13: ffffa0e3da5c4000 R14: ffffa0e3e1e0d050 R15: ffffa0e3e1e09000
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899036] FS:  00007f06e9bbcc40(0000) GS:ffffa0e3ef040000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899037] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899038] CR2: 00007f73408cc000 CR3: 0000000462606001 CR4: 00000000001606e0
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899039] Call Trace:
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899066]  nl80211_set_pmk+0x17a/0x250 [cfg80211]
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899073]  genl_family_rcv_msg+0x1b9/0x470
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899076]  ? __netlink_sendskb+0x42/0x50
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899080]  genl_rcv_msg+0x4c/0xa0
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899083]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899086]  ? genl_family_rcv_msg+0x470/0x470
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899088]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x50/0x120
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899091]  genl_rcv+0x29/0x40
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899094]  netlink_unicast+0x187/0x220
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899097]  netlink_sendmsg+0x20a/0x3c0
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899101]  sock_sendmsg+0x65/0x70
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899103]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x2ae/0x330
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899106]  ? call_rcu+0x10/0x20
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899109]  ? destroy_inode+0x65/0x80
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899111]  ? evict+0x14c/0x1b0
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899114]  ? dentry_free+0x3f/0x80
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899116]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899119]  ? get_max_files+0x20/0x20
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899123]  ? __cgroup_bpf_run_filter_setsockopt+0xb2/0x2a0
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899125]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899129]  ? aa_sk_perm+0x43/0x170
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899131]  __sys_sendmsg+0x5c/0xa0
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899133]  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1f/0x30
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899137]  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x130
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899140]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899142] RIP: 0033:0x7f06e9f43807
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899144] Code: 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb bb 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 2e 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 89 54 24 1c 48 89 74 24 10
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899145] RSP: 002b:00007ffe5d2e0848 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899147] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000564776eef5d0 RCX: 00007f06e9f43807
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899148] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007ffe5d2e0880 RDI: 0000000000000006
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899149] RBP: 0000564776f62a70 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 00007f06ea00ab80
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899150] R10: 00007ffe5d2e0954 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000564776eef4e0
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899151] R13: 00007ffe5d2e0880 R14: 00007ffe5d2e0954 R15: 0000564776f44330
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899153] ---[ end trace 84595d84ed5c268b ]---
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov kernel: [28134.899235] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov NetworkManager[883]: <info>  [1572311021.0946] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov NetworkManager[883]: <info>  [1572311021.0946] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "<NETWORK_NAME>"
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov NetworkManager[883]: <info>  [1572311021.0947] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> completed
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov NetworkManager[883]: <info>  [1572311021.0950] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov NetworkManager[883]: <info>  [1572311021.1014] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov avahi-daemon[875]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv6 with address xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx.
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov avahi-daemon[875]: New relevant interface wlp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov avahi-daemon[875]: Registering new address record for xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx on wlp4s0.*.
Oct 28 18:03:41 morozov xdg-desktop-por[2009]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Oct 28 18:03:44 morozov wpa_supplicant[887]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-11
Oct 28 18:03:44 morozov kernel: [28138.068345] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_scan: Scanning suppressed: status (4)
Oct 28 18:03:44 morozov geoclue[1329]: WiFi scan failed
Oct 28 18:03:45 morozov wpa_supplicant[887]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=84:18:3a:08:80:8c reason=2 locally_generated=1
Oct 28 18:03:45 morozov wpa_supplicant[887]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/1
Oct 28 18:03:45 morozov wpa_supplicant[887]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Oct 28 18:03:45 morozov NetworkManager[883]: <warn>  [1572311025.9977] sup-iface[0x556f2dd58a20,wlp4s0]: connection disconnected (reason -2)
Oct 28 18:03:46 morozov NetworkManager[883]: <info>  [1572311026.0008] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 28 18:03:46 morozov NetworkManager[883]: <info>  [1572311026.0008] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
```

As one can see, the authentication went well but something went wrong on the kernel level afterwards.

Is it a known bug in the Linux kernel (5.3.0-19-generic) and if so, is there a workaround?

Hardware information:

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: a0:99:9b:08:80:03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:59 memory:b0800000-b0807fff memory:b0400000-b07fffff
```